# Comment out a command line in bash using Readline

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, terminal

**The Situation**

I am writing a very long command in bash and eventually realise that I forgot to satisfy a prerequisite for that command. I want to store this command somewhere, perform all the requirements, restore the command back and execute it.

*Note: I want the command to stay on the screen*

Here is an example:

```
$ a very long command --path some_path and more arguments
```

So suppose this command requires that the some_path is an existing directory. However, while writing the command, I realise that I have not created that directory, so before executing the command I have to `mkdir some_path`.

**The Requirement**

What I would like to be able to do is the following:

```
$ a very long command --path some_path and more arguments [keystroke -> comment]
$ mkdir some_path
$ [up] [up] [keystroke -> uncomment]
```

or...

```
$ a very long command --path some_path and more arguments [keystroke -> comment]
$ mkdir some_path
$ [keystroke -> bring back, uncomment]
```

**My Solution**

To solve this problem I used the Readline bind tool and mapped `Control-P` character to a custom script in the following way:

```
function postpone {
   if [[ ${#READLINE_LINE} -gt 0 ]]
   then
      if [[ "${READLINE_LINE::1}" == "#" ]]
      then
         READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:1}"
      else
         READLINE_LINE="#$READLINE_LINE"
      fi
   else
      HIST_SIZE=`history | wc -l | tr -s ' ' | cut -d \  -f 2`
      for i in $(seq 1 $HIST_SIZE)
      do
         LINE=`history | sort -r | head -n $i | tail -n 1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d \  -f 3-`
         if [[ "${LINE::1}" == "#" ]]
         then
            READLINE_LINE="${LINE:1}"
            break
         fi
      done
   fi
}

bind -x '"\C-b": postpone'
bind '"\C-p":"\C-b\n"'
```

**And finally...The Question**

Can you suggest a better solution where I can go with a single mapping? The main focus is to eliminate the second mapping.

**Notes**

I learnt about `insert-comment` [bind function](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#Miscellaneous-Commands), but it will not work for me, as it only works on one direction. I also want to uncomment the line using the same shortcut.

Comment: Can this not be achieved using Ctrl-a Ctrl-k on the line you're writing, then Ctrl-y afterwards to paste it back in?

Comment: I'm with you Tom.  Either that or control a, `#`, enter, command, up, up, control a, delete the #.  Seems like an enormous amount of effort for an easily achieved result.

Comment: That is an option. at least I can map the `Ctrl-A Ctrl-K` combination to another shortcut. In this case I will not have the command stored in the history, however at the same time I will not have to go back through the history to uncomment it. Thanks a lot!!
Anyway imagine this problem during a demo, where you need to demonstrate the command syntax, but not actually execute it, and thus you would like the command to stay on the screen.

Comment: You can prefix a line always with a `#` by pressing Alt+#.

Comment: Off-topic but possibly of interest: the command line editor in `zsh` supports a command stack. You push the current command line on to the stack, execute your mkdir command, and the original command line is popped back as it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative:

1. At the end of your long line press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.
2. `mkdir some_path`
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> and continue your work.

Comment: That's a solution similar (and shorter) to what [Tom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/tom-fenech) suggested, however what I need is to have the command visible on the screen after switching to `mkdir some_path`.

Comment: Accepting as the only relevant answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to pass a numeric argument to `insert-comment`. If `insert-command` receives a numeric argument (any number, the value is not important), the command acts as a toggle:

- If the line is not commented, it adds a `#`.
- If the line is commented, it removes the `#`.

For example: `M-3 M-#` (`Alt-3 Alt-#`)